# Python string print formatting

Tags: python, string, printing, formatting

I'm very new to programming & Python. Still currently working on my first program. I had a little bit of help from this forum a week ago or so, but now I'm stuck on another part of the program so I'd need some kind sole to help me out again :-)

In this example I have 2 files `keyfile.dat` that contains the entire ascii charactor set, one character per line. They are the actual characters, NOT the codes.

`test.txt` works like an index file. Each line contains a number that points to a line number within `keyfile.dat` which in turn contains an ascii character. The code below prints letters of the alphabet, commas, question marks etc.. However it does not print spaces, carriage returns etc.. I guess this is because I am using `str.strip` within the `print` statement. If I do not use that command, instead of printing each character on the same line unless it reads a carriage return, it prints each character on a separate line. Basically this part of the program should print any character it is pointed to, regardless of what it is, and print it exactly as it is, just as like it was being typed.

---EDIT---
CODE REMOVED

Any ideas? & thanks in advance for any replies. Clinton.

Sample content of keyfile.dat

```
8
e
�
�
T
�
�
�
U
^V
�
^]
b
�
�
�
�
�
F
```

content test.txt:

```
14
203
163
38
52
163
38
188
231
11
38
231
242
208
74
163
38
163
231
```

Ouput using my code above:

```
T h i s , i s a t e s t ! O r i s i t ?
```

as you can see no spaces printed between words, and after ! there should be a carriage return.

Personally I think it is because of my print statement. I need to use .strip otherwise each character read from keyfile.dat gets printed on a new line. .strip to my knowledge removes spaces, carriage returns etc.. So if I read a carriage return & then try to print it, it gets stripped out because my print starement uses .strip.

Comment: you'd better use the with statement: `with open('keyfile.dat') as f: with open('test.txt') as i:` instead of `open`/`close`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `with` statement for handling file, as it automatically closes the file for you:

```
with open('keyfile.dat') as f, open('test.txt') as i:
    index = [int(line) for line in i)          #apply int() here
    keyfile = f.readlines()
    for ind in index:
        line = keyfile[ind]
        if len(line) > 1:
            print line[:-1],
        elif len(line) == 1:
            print line,
```

Comment: Hi Ashwini, that just prints 1 character per line & still excludes spaces, carriage returns etc.. Thanks for the reply though! Clinton.

Comment: @user2490853 please post `keyfile` and `test` file in question body.

Comment: sorry did not see all your code the first time I read it. I'll try again :-)

Comment: Stills prints one character per line & excludes spaces, carriages returns etc... Not sure why. I now tried your method plus several of my own. Always get the same result.

Comment: @user2490853 please post some sample data and expected output in the question body, it's not clear how your data looks like.

Comment: keyfile.dat look like: 5
f
�
�
^
�
�
�
�
�
Q
n
h
�
`
>
1
O

Comment: @user2490853 Post this is in the question body not comments.

Comment: forum will not let me answer my own question in order to provide you with th info your requested. Not able to provide detailsed info in this comment either. Not been a member long enough to answer my own questions. keyfile.dat has 1 ascii character per line, test.txt has 1 number per line which represents the line number to read from keyfile.dat. The code I originally posted prints all normal alphabet characters & punctuations. It does not print spaces, etc... I can only asume that this is either because I'm using .strip when I'm printing, or it's because keyfile contains the chars not ascii.

Comment: @user2490853 I am not saying you to post an answer, you can edit the question body and add some content there.

Comment: Hi Ashwini, I have as suggested added the content you requested to my original question. Sorry I did not realise that was what you meant for me to do.

Comment: Produce the same output as my code. T h i s , i s a t e s t ! O r i s i t ? no spaces printed & no carriage return after ! character.

Comment: Hi Ashwini, thatnks for all your help & time today. I think that I will leave this for now. May be I will re-write the program from scratch another day. Probably better if I just use ascii codes in future rather than the characters themselves. Take care, Clinton.

Comment: @user2490853 I am not sure what you're trying to do, but this works fine for me. Demo : http://ideone.com/f58ztu